# Regex pass dynamic values with boundry

Tags: c#, regex, string, boundary

I'm trying to pass a dynamic value at runtime with a boundary `\b` to a Regex function. 
My code is:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sent = "Accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass, barometer, gesture, heart rate";

            string match = "gyro";
            string bound = @"\b";

            if (Regex.IsMatch(sent, @"\bgyro", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("match is in the sentence");
            }
            else if (Regex.IsMatch(sent, bound+match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("match is in the sentence");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(bound+match); outputs \bgyro
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

First the `if` condition will be true since I'm passing the pattern to be matched directly. But when I'm trying to pass the pattern to be matched as in second condition it will be false. I tried to write the bound variable in console but it does not print any value in console either. Can some one give me a solution for this?

Comment: `@"\b"` is not the same as `"\b"`

Comment: What is your 2nd input (the one you are using to test the 2nd condition)? `Console.WriteLine(bound+match);` should output `\bgyro`, it is correct regex to match `gyro` that is at the start of a word (e.g. `gyrometer`). Or are you looking to match `gyro` as a whole word? Then, you need to add another `\b`: `string.Format("\\b{0}\\b", match)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regular expression has a black slash followed by the letter b because of that `@`.  The second one has the character that represents backspace.  Just put an `@` in front

```
string bound = @"\b";
```

Comment: @RavinduKotta Since it's an `else if` I wouldn't expect the second one to ever be `true` as it should just go into the `if` instead.

Comment: im sorry it was a stupid mistake my bad and thanks a lot @juharr